# SQL Server database internal version 831, after instaling a new sql instance the Data internal version is 782

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

At first I installed  SQL Server which I don't know which version it was as well Visual Studio 2015, after I had to uninstall SQL Server, I downloaded an SQL Server 2014 Express and suddenly the database that was created with the first installation will not open, the error I am getting is

> Database internal version is 831, while the instance internal version is 782

I couldn't find a newer version to download.

The first version instance was `(LocalDb)MSSQLLocalDB` while the SQL Server 2014 Express uses `SQLExpress`

Answer (score 1):

Internal version 782 is SQL Server **2014** - so it looks as if you've been using a pre-release version of SQL Server **2016** before.

Unfortunately, there's no way, hack, trick or workaround to "downgrade" an existing database file - you'll need to recreate the database in SQL Server 2014 Express based on your SQL scripts or your Entity Framework code-first migrations.

Comment: The solution was installing Server Data Tools 2015 for visual studio this pack installed a higher version of sql instance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was installing Server Data Tools 2015 for visual studio this pack installed a higher version of sql instance. – Omer David Feb 21 at 12:16